# Iterate through Django queryset within template

Tags: django, filter, iteration

I have created a custom filter that returns a queryset of objects.

in: templatetags

```
@register.filter(name = 'create_html_for_deleting_notes')
    def create_html_for_deleting_notes(task_pk):
    corresponding_notes = Note.objects.filter(its_task = Task.objects.filter(pk = task_pk))
    return(corresponding_notes)
```

in template:

```
{% for corresponding_task in corresponding_tasks %}
    <h5>{{ corresponding_task | create_html_for_deleting_notes }}<h5/>
{% endfor %}
```

This works in printing out my queryset. I would like to iterate through that queryset, something like:

in template:

```
{% for corresponding_task in corresponding_tasks %}
    {% for note in corresponding_task | create_html_for_deleting_notes %}
         {{ note }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this gives me the error 'for statements should use the format "for x in y"'

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the spaces around the filter `|` character.

However, I don't think you need the filter at all. You didn't post your model, but it seems like you have a foreignkey relationship between Task and Note, so you should just use the reverse accessor:

```
{% for corresponding_task in corresponding_tasks %}
    {% for note in corresponding_task.note_set.all %}
         {{ note }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have a foreignkey relationship between task and note.  Can you post a link of where I can see documentation on how to use this reverse accessor within a template?  Thank you.

Comment: You use it just like I showed you. But the docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Thank you so much!!!!

I also got this to work:


{% with corresponding_task.pk|create_html_for_deleting_notes as notes %}
{% for note in notes %}
<h5>{{ note }} <h5/>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}